# Image classifier ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_31 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1463, 224, 224, 3)

Tags: python-3.x, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to predict the genre of the movie from the data set for multilevel data. The input is like this

```
Id              Genre             Action    Adventure   Animation   Biography   Comedy  Crime   Documentary  Drama  Family  Fantasy History Horror  Music       
tt0086425   ['Comedy', 'Drama']    0           0           0           0           1      0         0          1       0      0       0        0      0

like this 25 columns of genre are there for each movie poster
```

I had done the EDA  and now trying to make predictive model for this multilevel data for which my my training and test separation looks like this

```
y = np.array(movies.drop(['Id', 'Genre'],axis=1))

from skmultilearn.model_selection import iterative_train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = iterative_train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape

o/p : ((5791, 224, 224, 3), (5791, 25), (1463, 224, 224, 3), (1463, 25))

y_test[0]

o/p :array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0], dtype=int64)

pd.DataFrame({
    'train': Counter(str(combination) for row in get_combination_wise_output_matrix(X_test, order=2) for combination in row),
    'test' : Counter(str(combination) for row in get_combination_wise_output_matrix(y_test, order=2) for combination in row)
}).T.fillna(0.0)

o/p:

    (0, 0)  (0, 1)  (0, 10) (0, 11) (0, 12) (0, 13) (0, 14) (0, 18) (0, 19) (0, 2)  ... (9, 13) (9, 14) (9, 18) (9, 19) (9, 20) (9, 21) (9, 22) (9, 23) (9, 24) (9, 9)
train   1074.0  323.0   11.0    56.0    2.0 4.0 41.0    40.0    148.0   33.0    ... 4.0 18.0    32.0    7.0 3.0 1.0 14.0    1.0 0.0 370.0
test    269.0   81.0    2.0 14.0    1.0 0.0 7.0 10.0    37.0    4.0 ... 2.0 4.0 20.0    2.0 0.0 0.0 4.0 0.0 1.0 97.0

2 rows × 228 columns
```

Now for creating predicting image classifier i have written this code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation="relu", input_shape=(224,224,3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(25, activation='sigmoid'))

model.summary()

Model: "sequential_12"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_41 (Conv2D)           (None, 220, 220, 16)      1216      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_41 (MaxPooling (None, 110, 110, 16)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_47 (Dropout)         (None, 110, 110, 16)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_42 (Conv2D)           (None, 106, 106, 32)      12832     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_42 (MaxPooling (None, 53, 53, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_48 (Dropout)         (None, 53, 53, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_43 (Conv2D)           (None, 49, 49, 64)        51264     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_43 (MaxPooling (None, 24, 24, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_49 (Dropout)         (None, 24, 24, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_44 (Conv2D)           (None, 20, 20, 64)        102464    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_44 (MaxPooling (None, 10, 10, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_50 (Dropout)         (None, 10, 10, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_12 (Flatten)         (None, 6400)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_29 (Dense)             (None, 128)               819328    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_51 (Dropout)         (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_30 (Dense)             (None, 64)                8256      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_52 (Dropout)         (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_31 (Dense)             (None, 25)                1625      
=================================================================
Total params: 996,985
Trainable params: 996,985
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

But once i run the model fit i am getting the value error:

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), batch_size=64)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
    793                 feed_output_shapes,
    794                 check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
--> 795                 exception_prefix='target')
    796 
    797             # Generate sample-wise weight values given the `sample_weight` and

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    129                         ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
    130                         str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
--> 131                         'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
    132                 if not check_batch_axis:
    133                     data_shape = data_shape[1:]

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_31 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1463, 224, 224, 3)
```

I am unable to figure out this last step how to fix this and where I had done the mistake as if already added flatten layer in between conv2d and dense layer however it did not fix. any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error lies on your target :

```py
X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape

o/p : ((5791, 224, 224, 3), (5791, 25), (1463, 224, 224, 3), (1463, 25))
```

Your y_train shape is `(1463, 224, 224, 3)` and not `(5791, 25)`, you got the wrong order.

The solution is then to replace the split line by:

```py
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = iterative_train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
```

[Here is the doc](http://scikit.ml/api/skmultilearn.model_selection.iterative_stratification.html)

Answer (score 2):

Contributing to the aforementioned solution, you have an additional mistake :

```
model.add(Dense(25, activation='sigmoid'))
```

As you have a multi-class classification problem, the correct activation function is `softmax`, not `sigmoid`.

Therefore, change your line to

`model.add(Dense(25, activation='softmax'))`.

Comment: yes 'softmax' has to be considered here thank you...also i did run my model and accuracy is about 91%, however having a glance on my code and from your experience can you  give your insight if its accuracy can be increased changing some architecture?

Comment: The accuracy metric may be misleading in case the dataset is imbalanced; in such cases, metrics such as F1-Score may be much more relevant. If the dataset is very well balanced, then the 91% accuracy is a very good one. In principle, you can improve your score by altering the input data or by changing the architecture.  Were I you, I would start by transfer-learning and use a well-established architecture, such as DenseNet/ResNet.

Comment: thanks i will try twigging architecture as well as use DenseNet..also have to plot my train accuracy with val accuracy...also if might have overfit and high accuracy would  a mislead